# draw an analogy / a parallel between A and B

Tags: synonyms

Are the phrases "draw an analogy between A and B" and "draw a parallel between A and B" synonymous?
Consider the following:

> He drew an analogy / a parallel between London and New York.

Some dictionaries seem to suggest "parallel" refers to a single point of similarity, while "analogy" is more comprehensive. I am not sure that distinction is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are reading your dictionaries correctly. "Analogy" and "parallel" have similar meanings, but they are pretty far from synonyms. A parallel is a commonality that you might notice between things, but an analogy would be a whole system of parallels that, like you say, is more comprehensive.